# How to plot the maximum and the minimum

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I am interested in drawing the minimum and the maximum of two variables, i.e. `min(x,y)` or `max(x,y)`. The way I was going about doing it so far was to get the contour plots using gnuplot but my attempts have not been successful.

The plots do not show well and I am not quite sure what the reason is. Here is what the code at the end of my post produces:

[image]

This is far from the actual functions, unfortunately. The maximum should be a square and the minimum two orthogonal lines as in the plot below.

[image]

Could you please help me reproduce these functions, if possible by adjusting my code?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={red!50!black},
        citecolor={black!50!black},
        urlcolor={blue!80!black}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$P_1$,
    ylabel=$P_2$,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot3[
    contour gnuplot={levels={0.02}}
    ]
    {min(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$P_1$,
    ylabel=$P_2$,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot3[
    contour gnuplot={levels={0.2}}
    ]
    {max(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Specify the domain: `\addplot3[domain=-0.2:1,......`

Comment: @HarishKumar That works wonders, thank you. If you like, post that as an answer too.

Comment: John I have added an answer, and add `samples` too for sharp edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `domain` and `samples` to the `\addplot3` options.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$P_1$,
    ylabel=$P_2$,
    xmin=-0.2,xmax=1,
    ymin=-0.2,ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot3[
    domain=-0.2:1,samples=100,contour gnuplot={levels={0.02}}
    ]
    {min(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$P_1$,
    ylabel=$P_2$,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot3[
    domain=0:1,samples=100,contour gnuplot={levels={0.9}}
    ]
    {max(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated!